# sticky sidebars in several div

Tags: javascript, css, sidebar, sticky

i got for each div an sidebar and i wanted do get all the sidebars  by scrolling down fixed.

you can find it here

```
var tmpWindow = $(window),
    sidebar = $('.sidebar'),
    sidebarHeight = sidebar.height(),
    offsetBottom = $('.content').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= sidebarHeight) {
        $('.sidebar').addClass('fixed');
        alert(sidebarHeight);
    } else {
        $('.sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dLdvv6um/

if i use the js it will disappear...

Comment: you should probably take your alert() out and use the console.log() it might help

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a class called "fixed", yet you don't have a class with that name specified in your css. Use .css() if you want to add straight css properties instead: .css({"position": "fixed"});.